# Var_Dump with mt_rand

Tags: php, mysql

the following statement is not returning any results. I've checked the SQL statements and they are correct also there appears to be no coding errors.

```
<?php

require_once "func.php";
require_once "websockets.php";

//  private $curResultId;
//  private $MaxResult;
//  private $MinResult;

for( $i = 0; $i<5; $i++ ) {
    $row = db_fetch_item("SELECT resultid FROM ResultPackage 
        where ResultPackage.slotid like '1'
        and ResultPackage.PackageID like '1'
        ORDER BY resultid desc LIMIT 1");
    $this->MaxResult = $row['resultid'];


    $row = db_fetch_item("SELECT resultid FROM ResultPackage 
        where ResultPackage.slotid like '1'
        and ResultPackage.PackageID like '1'
        ORDER BY resultid asc LIMIT 1");
    $this->MinResult = $row['resultid'];

    $this->curResultId = mt_rand($this->MinResult,$this->MaxResult);


        var_dump($this->curResultId);


    }

?>
```

Please help

Comment: Do `$this->MaxResult` and `$this->MinResult` have expected values? What php version do you use?

Comment: PHP Version => 5.6.22-0+deb8u1
Yes min =1 and max = 14

Comment: What do you mean by `the following statement is not returning any results.` ? If MaxResult=14 and MinResult=1 your sql queries are obviously returning results. What does `var_dump($this->MinResult, $this->MaxResult, $this->curResultId);` print exactly?

Comment: @ccKep That statement doesnt return any results either

Comment: @Rnadmo Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: This is not your complete code is it? By that I mean: It *is* inside a class right? (regarding `$this`) If it's not and this is your complete file then `$this` is undefined, you can't access `undefined->MaxResult/MinResult/curResultId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `$this`? Is this part of a class method or that's all your script? If it's not a class, you should use other variables instead of `$this`.

```
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $row = db_fetch_item("SELECT resultid FROM ResultPackage 
        where ResultPackage.slotid like '1'
        and ResultPackage.PackageID like '1'
        ORDER BY resultid desc LIMIT 1");
    $MaxResult = $row['resultid'];

    $row = db_fetch_item("SELECT resultid FROM ResultPackage 
        where ResultPackage.slotid like '1'
        and ResultPackage.PackageID like '1'
        ORDER BY resultid asc LIMIT 1");
    $MinResult = $row['resultid'];

    $curResultId = mt_rand($MinResult,$MaxResult);

    var_dump($curResultId);
}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect except it returns the results as int(14) int(26) int(34) int(48) int(59) and I just need the numbers